# cx_Freeze: ImportError: No module named 'PyQt5.Qt'

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, cx-freeze

I am trying to build my GUI application using `cx_Freeze`. The `setup.py` is as follows:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os
import sys

base = None

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'

exe = [Executable("main.py", base=base, icon='window_icon_XbH_icon.ico')]

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\\Users\\dm\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\tcl\\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\\Users\\dm\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\tcl\\tk8.6'

options = {
'build_exe': {
    'includes': ['scipy.io', 'scipy.spatial.ckdtree'],

    'include_files': [r'C:\\Users\\dm\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\DLLs\\tcl86t.dll', r'C:\\Users\\dm\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\DLLs\\tk86t.dll',
                      r'C:\\Users\\dm\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\Lib\\site-packages\\pyqt5_tools\\platforms\\qwindows.dll', 'window_icon_XbH_icon.ico'],
    'packages': ['pkg_resources._vendor', 'pandas', 'numpy', 'scipy', 'pydub', 'PyQt5', 'soundfile', 'sounddevice', 'cffi'],
}
}

setup(name="app", version="1.0", description='To be added',
  options=options, executables=exe)
```

While building, the cx_Freeze is through the following error. I have installed PyQt5.

```
running build
running build_exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 38, in <module>
options=options, executables=exe)
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 349, in setup
distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 219, in run
freezer.Freeze()
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 616, in Freeze
self.finder = self._GetModuleFinder()
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 342, in _GetModuleFinder
finder.IncludePackage(name)
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 659, in IncludePackage
module = self._ImportModule(name, deferredImports)
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 351, in _ImportModule
raise ImportError("No module named %r" % name)
ImportError: No module named 'PyQt5.Qt'
```

Could anyone help me to figre out what is actually going wrong?

Comment: Which version of cx_Freeze are you using?

Comment: @jpeg The latest one. cx_Freeze 5.1.1

Answer (score 3):

Don't capitalize PyQt5. Try pyqt5 in the setup.py file.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but today I faced this problem.

This is how I solved it:

Removed PyQt5 and everything that was related to it from my `setup.py` `('{"build_exe": {"packages":' <- this part).`
After it compiled my exe.
If you run the exe and theres a missing PyQt5 module error, then from your site-packages directory 
`(path similar to this: d:\Python37\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\)`
 copy the whole PyQt5 directory to your cx_freeze built lib directory `(example: ..\build\exe.win-amd64-3.7\lib\)`

Now try to run the exe and there should be no missing module error, at least related to PyQt5.
If you have any other missing module problem, then just copy it from your site-packages into the lib directory. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the (unnecessary?) line

```
import PyQt5.Qt
```

from your `setup.py` script.

EDIT after the OP removed this line:

1. Try to remove the unnecessary `os.environ` statements, these are for `tkinter`, maybe they conflict. Remove the 3 DLLs entries in the `include_files` (keep only the icon). Add `'atexit'` to the `includes` list, see the [cx_Freeze PyQt5 example](https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze/tree/master/cx_Freeze/samples/PyQt5).
2. Try to re-install `PyQt5` and `cx_Freeze`, see potential caveats in [ImportError: No module named PytQt5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20672918/8516269) and [PyQt5 and QtGui module not found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17388082/8516269).
3. If this still does not work, maybe there is a conflict with another package used in your application. To find out, make a minimal example using only `PyQt5`, such as the [cx_Freeze PyQt5 example](https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze/tree/master/cx_Freeze/samples/PyQt5) and try to freeze it. If it works, add the other packages one by one, checking the frozen application at each step.

EDIT II:

4. A further possibility is that you have a conflict with `PyQt4` if it is or has been installed on your system. Make sure to remove any import of `PyQt4` from your application and maybe add an entry `excludes: ['PyQt4']` to the `build_exe` dictionary in your `setup.py` script.

Comment: But I guess you get a different error message then.

Comment: I don't know why cx_Freeze is not able to locate PyQt5.

Comment: What happens if you type import PyQt5.Qt in a python console?

Comment: @M.Denis I've added further proposals to my answer.

Comment: Removing PyQt5 from the packages list gets rid of the error message. But I am getting the following attribute error while running the app. The error is `AttributeError: function 'LLVMPY_OffsetOfElement not found`.

Comment: What is the full traceback? Which DLL should provide the function which is not found? Try to add this DLL to your distribution directory or to its `lib` subdirectory. Is your GUI based on `PyQt5` or on another GUI library? If yes, have you tried to add `import PyQt5` to your main application script?

Comment: I am still trying to figure that out. But I am sure that it is a version conflict. I was able to freeze the application last week and now I can't because I reinstalled my OS.

Comment: Interesting. Maybe your new OS provides incompatible versions of (some of) the Qt DLLs and the frozen application looks for these DLLs in the wrong place, does not find them, falls back using the PATH environment variable, and finds the wrong one. Once you have frozen your application, try to make copies of the Qt DLLs which should be in some subdirectory of the build directory into the build directory itself and into its `lib` subdirectory.