# i can't rebuild because of some error in python?

Tags: python, import

I don't know what happen my code.

I can't rebuild some error.

```
import os
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QToolTip, QPushButton, QMainWindow
from time import strftime
```

> Unused import ospylint(unused-import)
>
> Undefined variable: 'QtWidgets'Python(undefined-variable)

Comment: There are [quite a few other questions](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=pyqt5.qtwidgets+not+found+site:stackoverflow.com) relating to this on SO. Do they help?

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388082/pyqt5-and-qtgui-module-not-found/20904887)